# Random processes with smooth paths

Tags: random-functions, set-valued-analysis

Is there any prototypical example of a Random process with smooth paths?

I imagine one can simple integrate each path of a Brownian motion and get a $C^{\frac32-\epsilon}$ path.

It's easy to describe paths of Brownian bridges over a circle using Fourier expansion and the normal distribution:

$$
B(w, x) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} C_n(w) e^{inx}
$$

- $C_n \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ we obtain White Noise.
- $C_n \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\left< n \right>^{-2})$ we obtain a Brownian Bridge, paths are a.s. in $H^{\frac12-\epsilon}$
- $C_n \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\left< n \right>^{-4})$ paths are a.s. in $H^{\frac32-\epsilon}$, so we now have at least one derivative.
- $C_n \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\left< n \right>^{-2k})$ paths are a.s. in $H^{\frac{2k-1}{2}-\epsilon}$, so we now have at least $k$ derivatives.
- For a $C^\infty$ maybe with $C_n \sim \mathcal{N}(0,e^{-\left< n \right>})$ paths would be a.s. in $C^\infty$?.

I can't find any literature about non-trivial random processes with smooth paths.

Do you know of any literature related with it?

I'm trying to understand something on set-valued functions, and the way an integral for such functions is defined seems related to random processes (http://econweb.ucsd.edu/~rstarr/201/Aumann%20Journal%20of%20Mathematical%20Analysis%20and%20Applications%201965.pdf).

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A good place to read about this is Adler and Taylor's book *Random Fields and Geometry*.   Regular random processes  or functions are  used more frequently in integral geometry.

Consider  the more general  Gaussian  process  on $S^1$ $\newcommand{\bZ}{\mathbb{Z}}$ $\newcommand{\ii}{\boldsymbol{i}}$

$$  F(\theta)=\sum_{n\in\bZ} C_n e^{n\ii \theta},  $$

where $C_n$  are independent  centered Gaussian random variables. Then $F$ is   a.s. smooth if $\newcommand{\vfi}{\varphi}$ $\newcommand{\bE}{\mathbb{E}}$  $\newcommand{\var}{\boldsymbol{var}}$ the  covariance kernel

$$K(\theta,\vfi)=\bE\bigl[ F(\theta)\overline{F(\vfi)}\bigr]= \sum_{n\in\bZ}\var[C_n] e^{\ii n(\theta-\vfi)} $$

is smooth. This happens if

$$\sum_{n\in\bZ} n^{2s}\var[C_n]<\infty,\;\;\forall s>0. $$

For stationary processes like this one this condition is also necessary.

Answer (score 1):

One way to get a $C^{\infty}$ path from a Brownian motion, without changing the original path too much, is to [mollify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier) it.

Comment: Hi, right, ultimately is just a multiplication on the Fourier expansion by a fast decaying function, as you multiply a normal r.v. the term would go to the variance similar as in the last example, which would ensure that any $H^k$ norm is finite, but there is any real usage of this? any literature about it?